# Why JSF page keeps old data?

Tags: jsf

I have an simple create page, and save button. First time I run application everything is fine but after that it keeps values from previous creation.

```
<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.CreateProjectsTitle}"></h:outputText>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="body">
        <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
            <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateProjectsLabel_projectName}"
                               for="projectName"/>

                <h:inputText  id="projectName"
                              value="#{projectsController.selected.projectName}"
                              title="#{bundle.CreateProjectsTitle_projectName}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <p:commandButton action="#{projectsController.create}"
                             value="#{bundle.CreateProjectsSaveLink}"
                             onclick="window.close()"/>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: What is the scope of `projectsController`?

Comment: it is @SessionScoped i should change it to @ RequestScoped  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `projectsController` is session scoped, it is instantiated once and that instance is kept as long the session is alive. When you enter values in its fields, they stay there until you change them.

Your options are

- Change the scope to `@RequestScope`, that way the bean will be initialized on each request
- Reset the values you want in some action, possibly after the button's action is completed

Answer (score 2):

The values on your page are stored in your Java objects bound to the page. In this case, `projectsController`.

The java objects have a lifetime according to the scope you have defined for them. So as long as that scope lasts, the values on the page will remain, unless you explicitly do something with them.

If you expect the page to be reset each time it is submitted, you should make it request scoped.